# Specify string date format before casting in a function SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario to cast string date into date format. But the date string is not in a straight format, so the conversion throws error. So what I tried is

```
set dateformat dmy
```

before the casting in sql and it worked without any issue.

But the trouble is I need this to implement in a view or function. But the disappointing part, function or view doesn't support **set dateformat** with which it says as **side effecting operator**

So how can I specify the date format of the given string before casting in a function or view?

Comment: can you provide your string date and required date format sample

Comment: Ideally, don't let yourself get into this situation. Why are you allowing datetime data to flow through your system in anything but *appropriate* data types? If you "have" to allow strings, can you not enforce ISO 8601 formats?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The issue is we are dealing with data (historical) which was entered couple of years back.. if any new we are only allowing in ISO format.

Answer (score 0):

As Damien wrote in his comment to the question, ideally you should not mess around with string representations of datetime in the first place - you should be using proper data types - and since you asked about creating a view, it can only mean that somewhere in your database there's a datetime value stored as a string.
The solution to this situation is to change the way you are storing this value - use `DateTime2` for datetime values, `Date` for date-only values, or `Time` for time-of-day values.

Further reading - Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Assuming you can't change the database design, read the rest of this answer.

You can't use `set dateformat` on a view or a function, but you can use `convert` instead of `cast` to change the string representation of a `datetime` value into an actual `datetime` value, assuming the string representation has one of the [supported date formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) (there are quite a few of them, so usually it shouldn't be a problem).

If your string representation of the `datetime` is in a format that is not supported by the built in `convert` function, you might need to do some extra work in the form of string manipulation to either change it into a supported format, or (in the harder case) separate the string representation to parts and then use [`datetimefromparts.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If you could provide the actual format you are using in your string representation of the `datetime` format I can probably edit this answer to show you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The third [parameter of `CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) allows to provide a format type.

Assuming your `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` I take you've to deal with dates like "1/2/2000", meaning the first of February in 2000.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(100)='1/2/2000';

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@d,104)
```

The `104` is the *German* type with a 4-digit year. If this does not fit your needs, you can follow the link to find a better suiting format.

If you need further help, please provide samples of your actual dates.

**Hint**: You should always store a value in a column with the appropriate type. Storing dates as strings will make things slow and opens a lot of error sources...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST('07/01/2018' AS DATE),23)
```

Result

```
2018-07-01
```

Comment: Your `cast(... as date)` is relying on default settings implicitly... Something you really don't want...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by, "date string is not in a straight format".  Examples will help.
Have you tried parsing, instead of casting?

```
SELECT 
    TRY_PARSE(thedate AS datetime)  as justParse
    ,TRY_PARSE(thedate AS datetime USING 'en-US') as parseUS
    ,TRY_PARSE(thedate AS datetime USING 'en-GB') as parseGB
    ,try_cast(thedate as date) as tryCast
FROM (values 
('07/01/2018')
,('01/07/2018')
,('07 jan 2018')
,('jan 07 2018')
,('Monday, 7 January 2019')
)d(thedate)
```